# Barcode Scanning Module for processing in odoo10

Tags: api, mobile, odoo, odoo-10

My project in odoo10 depends on barcode scanning system. And this barcode scanning via mobile system.

We Want to retrieve sale order information by mobile barcode scanning. So, Anyone can help me for this problem?

Comment: You need to modify your mobile application to send the scanned barcode to Odoo over Odoo-API